# Get the SPFolder programmatically and apply permission

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I need to get the folder object, `SPFolder` using C# in my SP 2013 on-prem site collection.

Below code, I have created a new folder programmatically.

Now how can I get this `SPFolder` object and later I wanna apply `Contribute` permissions for this folder?

It would be good, if i can get `GUID` approach.
There is only one param, we need to pass , thats `GUID`, but how to retrieve the `GUID` of the folder.

```
try
{
    SPList marketrsrchDocLib = paramCurrentWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MarketResearch");
    if (marketrsrchDocLib != null)
    {
        listitemDivisionFolder = marketrsrchDocLib.Items.Add("", 
                                  SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, strDivisionNameCreated);
        listitemDivisionFolder.Update();
     }
     marketrsrchDocLib.Update();

     //now apply permissionsfor the folder -
     SPFolder folder =   paramCurrentWeb.GetFolder(???) 
     //?? what should be the correct code here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Can you try out the below sample code that I took from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2007/11/15/how-to-programmatically-set-permissions-on-filesfolders-in-a-sharepoint-document-library/) - I have a online enviornment, hence couldnt try,

```
SPFolder folder = SharePointConfiguration.Site.GetFolder(path); //path of the folder
SPGroupCollection spc = SharePointConfiguration.Site.SiteGroups;
SPGroup group = spc[groupName]; //name of the group with the contribute permissions
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)group);
folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(SharePointConfiguration.Site.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]);
folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

Basically, this is taking a folder instance by path, picking up the relevant group and assigning permissions as specified.

[Source : MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2007/11/15/how-to-programmatically-set-permissions-on-filesfolders-in-a-sharepoint-document-library/)

Comment: Whats the value of the path variable?

Comment: would be in the format `<sp site url>/<Library Name>/<Folder>`